# Spring batch - Improve write performance jdbc

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch job with a step consisting or reader(reading from elastic search), processor(flattening and giving me a list of items) and writer(writing in database the list of item) running as following

```
  @Bean
  public Step userAuditStep(
      StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
      ItemReader<User> esUserReader,
      ItemProcessor<Product, List<UserAuditFact>>
          userAuditFactProcessor,
      ItemWriter<List<UserAuditFact>> userAuditFactListItemWriter) {
    return stepBuilderFactory
        .get(stepName)
        .<Product, List<UserAuditFact>>chunk(chunkSize)
        .reader(esUserReader)
        .processor(userAuditFactProcessor)
        .writer(userAuditFactListItemWriter)
        .listener(listener)
        .build();
  }
```

As you can see above user reader(just kept batch reader size 2) gives list of userAudit(which are usually in few thousands) and then writing using a listWriter which is something like below

```
  @Bean
  @StepScope
  public ItemWriter<List<UserAuditFact>>
      userAuditFactListItemWriter(
          ItemWriter<UserAuditFact> userAuditFactItemWriter) {
    return new UserAuditFactListUnwrapWriter(userAuditFactItemWriter);
  }

  @Bean
  @StepScope
  public ItemWriter<UserAuditFact> userAuditFactItemWriter(
      @Qualifier("dbTemplate") NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<UserAuditFact>()
        .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(
            UserAuditFactQueryProvider
                .getUserAuditFactInsertParams())
        .assertUpdates(false)
        .sql(UserAuditFactQueryProvider.UPSERT)
        .namedParametersJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate)
        .build();
  }
```

So since I am having a list of Items, I am unwrapping them before writing into database like below

```
public class UserAuditFactListUnwrapWriter
    implements ItemWriter<List<UserFact>> {
  private final ItemWriter<UserAuditFact> delegate;

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends List<UserAuditFact>> lists) throws Exception {
    final List<UserAuditFact> consolidatedList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final List<UserAuditFact> list : lists) {
      consolidatedList.addAll(list);
    }
    delegate.write(consolidatedList);
  }
}
```

Now the write operation is taking a lot of time especially when there is lot of items in consolidatedList

One option I can do is do some chunking logic like following where I split the list to some chunk and then give to delegate like shown below

```
public class UserAuditFactListUnwrapWriter
        implements ItemWriter<List<UserFact>> {
      private final ItemWriter<UserAuditFact> delegate; 
      @Setter private int chunkSize = 0; // Maybe chunksize of 200
    
      @Override
      public void write(List<? extends List<UserAuditFact>> lists) throws Exception {
        final List<UserAuditFact> consolidatedList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final List<UserAuditFact> list : lists) {
          consolidatedList.addAll(list);
        }
        List<List<T>> partitions = ListUtils.partition(consolidatedList, chunkSize);
        for (List<T> partition : partitions) {
          delegate.write(partition);
         }
      }
    }
```

However, this too does not give me needed performance. Imagine 60000 records (3000 partitions with each chunk of 200) takes long

I was wondering if i can make it better further (maybe someway to have the partitions to be written in parallel)

Some additional info.
Database is AWS postgres rds

Comment: I think that the jdbc batch update is *not* what is performing poorly here, it is rather the list of list management in memory (especially that you are using an `ArrayList`, that is resized frequently). You could verify that by  checking the sql query that is run against the BD and run it outside the job, in order to measure its performance in isolation.

Comment: @FadhelMahmoudBenHassine Thank you for reply and pointing me to right direction. In such case where in there is list of items that needs to be written what would be the right way to go about in spring batch (changing the datatype to set or some other way to handle this scenario)

Comment: It really depends on your domain model. For a single item, how many tables would be impacted to insert it in the database? This is key because if multiple tables are involved, Spring Batch won't be able to help here, the insert query + the chunk size would be the two most important parameters to play with in order to improve the performance of your step.